# aspx Div scrolling issue

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a GridView inside Scrolling div, which looks nice but the problem is that my grid has one column with a picture, so the scrolling is slow and heavy.

Any idea?

Thanks.

div:

```
 <div style="border : solid 1px ; padding : 4px; width:640px; height : 550px; overflow : auto; ">
```

Comment: Weird.. You said 1MB each picture. I just tried this with 3MB pictures and the scrolling was fine. Though I used a table, not a gridview, but I don't think that would matter. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is your picture? I would try reducing the res of your pic and see if it goes any faster.

**Edit:** Just to be sure it is the problem, have you tried it without the picture column? Also, how many rows are there with 1MB pictures? That's 1MB a row. If you have a bunch of rows, that could be the issue too. Do some testing and try to narrow down the problem.